# Experience Editor Permissions - How to edit rendering parameters

Tags: experience-editor, role-management, permissions

I have a Sitecore 9.3 instance. I have create a role for my users. It is a member of the following roles:

```
Analytics Management Reporting
Analytics Content Profiling
Analytics Maintaining
Analytics Personalization
Analytics Testing
Analytics Advanced Testing
Analytics Reporting
Designer
Author
```

But in the Content Editor and Experience Editor rendering parameters are greyed out and not editable. I thought Designer was supposed to cover this?

Comment: I think you need the Sitecore Client Designing role.

Comment: I believe that is included in Designer

Answer (score 0):

So, I dont love this solution, but I had to set explicit write permissions on my rendering parameter templates. There must be a better solution, but technically this worked.

Comment: You can also use the "Details" and "Access Viewer" buttons before setting up permissions in the Content Editor ribbon -> Security tab -> Security chunk.